# Disable Login details from being autofilled into input fields .Net Core Identity

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

When I want to create an account I don't want any fields being populated by chrome passwords as I have a hidden field that appears if a certain option is selected from a select.  The field is shown, but if the user then uses the chrome password autofill then the email address is put in the wrong place see diagram -

[image]

I have tried autocomplete = "off",  AutoCompleteType="Disabled".  Doesn't work.

Code -

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create account";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Administration</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" id="RegisterForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled">
            <h5>Create a new account.</h5>
            <hr />

            @*             <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            *@

            <input id="vaccClinicId" asp-for="Input.VaccinationClinicId" style="display:none" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.UserRole"></label>
                <select asp-for="Input.UserRole" class="form-control selectrole" asp-items="ViewBag.RoleId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserRole" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group YFVCNumber">
                <label asp-for="Input.YFVCNumber"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.YFVCNumber" type="text" class="form-control YFVCNumberInput" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.YFVCNumber" class="text-danger YFVCError"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control EmailInput" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit">Create Account</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input:text, form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
            $("input:password, form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
            CheckRole();
        });

        $(".selectrole").change(function () {
            CheckRole();
        });

        $(".selectrole").click(function () {
            CheckRole();
        });

        function CheckRole() {
            if ($(".selectrole option:selected").text() != "VCStaff") {
                $(".YFVCNumberInput").attr("required", false);
                $('.EmailInput').attr('disabled', false);
                $(".YFVCNumber").hide();
            }
            else {
                $(".YFVCNumberInput").attr("required", true);
                $('.EmailInput').attr('disabled', true);
                $(".YFVCNumber").show();
            }
        };
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TOO much so I put in as an answer - although might not fully be a enough to fully answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be enough but is a rework of the basic code.

NOTE: you MAY have to put this in the HTML markup on an element if the browser is doing it too fast/before you can change via script: `autocomplete="none"` or `autocomplete="off"`

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").find("input[type='text']")
    .add("input[type='password']")
    .prop("autocomplete", "off"); // should this be .prop("autocomplete", false); perhaps?
  // attach then trigger the event:
  $(".selectrole").on('change click', CheckRole)
    .trigger('change');
});

function CheckRole(event) {
  const thisSelect = $(this);
  const isNotVCStaff = !thisSelect.find("option:selected").text() != "VCStaff";
  // might also be (but not sure the rendered select values):
  // const isVCStaff = !thisSelect.val() != "VCStaff";
  const thisForm = thisSelect.closest('form');
  // these can all be based on the bool value:
  thisForm.find(".YFVCNumberInput").prop("required", isNotVCStaff);
  thisForm.find('.EmailInput').prop('disabled', isNotVCStaff);

  //savm effect as show() hide() but we use one with bool
  thisForm.find(".YFVCNumber").toggle(isNotVCStaff);
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat.  Thanks Mark Schultheiss